# How to have UIView component in UIStackview shared in Size Classes

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uistackview

If I have a `UIStackview` used in a xib for both iPhone and iPad.

This `UIStackview` contains couple of UIView components and 1 of them is a button.

If this button is in the `UIStackview` in iPhone, but outside of `UIStackview` in iPad. There will be a problem.

If I try to have two exact same buttons but 1 appear only in iPhone another 1 only appear in iPad. When I link them to the exact same `IBOutlet`, there's only 1 that I can link to it.

I don't want to have a duplicate `IBOutlet` having the same style doing the same work, and I don't want to have a duplicate UIComponent in the xib 1 in `UIStackview` and 1 out of it either.

What's the best way to solve this issue?

Comment: UIStackView is horizontal or vertical ??

Comment: @DineshBalasubramanian it's a horizontal stack view but in this case it shouldn't matter.

Comment: Sadly I think that you can't link 2 buttons to the same IBOutlet, even though they are size-classed

Comment: @Roux yeah I know this part.. but in my case, how would I achieve the same result?

Comment: You could make a collection of UIButtons, set the logic, UI and target afterward